# How to specify an Twitter endpoint using Tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm using tweepy trying to get history tweets from a specific user, for example "IBM"
In TwitterAPI I can use

```
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
end_point = 'tweets/search/30day/:development'
param = {'query': 'from:IBM', 'maxResults':'500'}
r = TwitterPager(api, end_point, param)
```

To specify the end point. I'm wondering how I can do similar in Tweepy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with Tweepy. `tweets/search/30day` is a Premium Search endpoint. Tweepy does not support the Premium Search API.